# Invalid attempt to Read when reader is closed. C# Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

This script is on the register page of my visual basic application.
The script saves the data in the database with no errors only when i close the application it gives me the error invalid attempt to read when reader is closed. This only happens on this page

```
 if (PasswordRegister.Text == RepeatPasswordRegister.Text)
        {

            if (PasswordRegister.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter a vailed password");
            }
            else if (UsernameRegister.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter a vailed Username");
            }
            else {

            string myConnection = "datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=Root;";
            MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);

            MySqlCommand Login = new MySqlCommand("select * from database.users where Username='" + this.UsernameRegister.Text + "' ;", myConn);

            MySqlDataReader RegisterReader;
            myConn.Open();
            RegisterReader = Login.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 0;
            while (RegisterReader.Read())
            {
                count = count + 1;
            }
            if (count == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username is taken");
            }
            else if (count > 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR Contact support");
            }
            else {


                    string constring = "datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=Root;";
                    string Query = "insert into database.users (Username, Password) values ('" + this.UsernameRegister.Text + "','" + this.PasswordRegister.Text + "') ;";
                    MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
                    MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
                    MySqlDataReader myReader;
                    try
                    {
                        conDataBase.Open();
                        myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
                        MessageBox.Show("Register Succes");
                        conDataBase.Close();
                        conDataBase.Dispose();
                        this.Hide();
                        Form1 home = new Form1();
                        home.ShowDialog();
                        while (myReader.Read())
                        {

                        }
                    }


                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }

                }
            myConn.Close();
        }
        }
        else {
            MessageBox.Show("Check password");
        };
```

Comment: You close your connection before finish using reader.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your code carefully, you'll note that you've closed the connection before you try and read from the reader:

```
conDataBase.Open();
myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
conDataBase.Close(); *** Connection closed here
conDataBase.Dispose(); *** And disposed disposed, for good measure
...
while (myReader.Read())  *** Now you are trying to Read!
{

}
```

What you need to do is keep the connection Open until you've finished reading, e.g.

```
using (var myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection))
using (var Login = new MySqlCommand("select * from database.users where Username= @myUserName", 
       myConn);
{
  cmdDataBase.AddWithValue(new MySqlParameter("@myUserName", this.UsernameRegister.Text));
  conDataBase.Open();
  using (var myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader())
  {
      while (myReader.Read())
      {
           // Do something with myReader[] fields here
      }
  } // Reader disposed
} // Command Disposed, Connection Closed + Disposed
```

I would also prefer the `using` syntax to manage disposables such as Connections, Commands, and Readers, and at the same time, parameterize your queries and commands - this has security, and possibly also performance benefit.